# Multiple redirects on lighttpd

Tags: javascript, redirection, lighttpd

I have a request to redirect multiple individual URLs to new individual URLs. This is the situation:

```
**Old URL                         -->     New URL**
old.domain.org/                   -->  new.domain.net/inf/site1.html
old.domain.org/#data/re/sys.html  -->  new.domain.net/inf/site2.html 
old.domain.org/#data/rq/opr.html  -->  new.domain.net/inf/site3.html
```

I created a redirect file with this code:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "old.domain.org" {
       url.redirect = ("^/$" => "http://new.domain.net/inf/site1.html",
       "^/#data/re/sys.html" => "http://new.domain.net/inf/site2.html",
       "^/#data/rq/opr.html" => "http://new.domain.net/inf/site3.html"
       )
}
```

But this does not work for me; because, when i go to `http://old.domain.org/#data/re/sys.html` the lighttpd redirect to `http://new.domain.net/inf/site1.html#data/re/sys.html` ... that does not exist.

I'm not developer, but I think that the problem is the "#" character.. someone said me that thats part is a javascript function. So, how I do to go to old urls to the new urls?

Comment: you are correct.  lighttpd never sees the `#` or anything after it, that is all handled on the client side.  so, the short answer is you can't do it with just lighttpd.

Comment: how i could do it? lighttpd and what else?

Comment: I would suggest taking this question over to http://serverfault.com or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com (flag the question for moderator attention, and just put a note that you'd like it moved.). The folks over there have probably run into this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with lighttpd but at a guess you might try [URL perecent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), since # is a reserved character in URLs.

Try replacing #data with %23data.